# Second child div height fill parent height

Tags: css, height, parent

I have a div (article) which has two childs (header and #content_outer). Header has a correct height, and I would like #content_outer to have a height (without giving a specific number for example:200px) so that header height + #content_outer height = article height.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyNX4/

(In the fiddle #content_outer shouldn't exceed article div in the bottom)

I would like that the solution is only with css.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, this is my desired solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fyNX4/5/

I gave #content_outer  --> height:240px;

But I would like to give a height with % or other solution that could apply if the header had more text (and have more height). ( http://jsfiddle.net/fyNX4/8/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fyNX4/9/

I had to modify your structure by adding some otherwise unnecessary markup:

```
table:   table-row:       table-cell:       cell's content:
article  header           span
article  div#content-row  div#content-cell  div#content: overflow:auto;
```

- `table-row`s are necessary because they are the only way to order table cells vertically
- `table-cell`s are necessary, because `table-row`s don't accept padding or height.
- internal wrapper div was necessary because `table-cell`s ignore `overflow`

Comment: "Of course" it won't work with IE 6/7, so you have to find out some alternative, if necessary.

Comment: A comment from user Stefan: "This solution currently only works in Google Chrome browser, not e.g. in current versions of Internet Explorer or Firefox. There the content div doesn't scroll, but fits to it's inner text height and overlaps the outer divs."

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

Here is the updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fyNX4/6/

```
#main { width: 300px; height:300px;  background:Khaki; overflow:auto;}
#content_outer { background: GoldenRod;  height:100%; }
```

Comment: No, #main should have the given height:300px; and there should appear a scroll in #content_outer