# Highchart overflows modal window

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JtXvOuPhdGVo3ZF0XTaq?p=preview) I have a Highcharts chart in an Angular UI modal window. The modal window has height and width declared in a class, and the chart is supposed to strech to width/height however it overflows at the bottom (possibly because it has two divs on top with text). How to make it fit?

**Note**: the chart has to be below the text divs, not as background.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
     <div>some text</div>
     <div>more text</div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; width:100%; height:100%;">    </div>
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$uibModal,$timeout) {

      var modalInstance;
      $scope.open = function () {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: false,
              windowClass: 'the-modal',
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
            });

            $timeout(function(){
                plotChart();
            });

        };

        var plotChart = function(){

              $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });

        };

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is right, the presence of child div elements and setting `height:100%;` for chart container cause overflow for the parent container. One option to fix this issue is to use [CSS3's Flexible Box Layout Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), another options are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11226029/1375553).

**Using [CSS3's Flexible Box Layout Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)**

Enable a `Flexbox Layout` for a parent container (modal dialog)

```
.the-modal .modal-content{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

and then set chart container to occupy the remaining space  via `flex-grow`, in your case replace:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```

with

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; width:100%; flex-grow: 1;"></div>
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kD7zOZoyd6jwvrFYrobV?p=preview)

Comment: the chart is on top of the bottom border, can the chart be within the div? Also, why did you add the `reflow()` function?

Comment: Sure, see [Design and style](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style) for a more details (margin and spacing options)

Comment: @ps0604,  reflow function could be omitted here, I simply forgot to remove it