# v-tabs in vuetify is not taking 100% height

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

The `v-tabs` component doesn't take 100% height. Upon inspecting, I could see that all the tab items (i.e. tab contents) are being wrapped inside a

```
<div class='v-tab__items'>  
  your content  
</div>
```

How do target the `v-tab__items` class? Or is there another way to achieve the same? I have tried the `height` API from Vuetify, which did not yeild the desired result.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553663/how-to-make-v-tabs-items-and-v-tab-item-fill-height/56882119#56882119

Answer (score 7):

### Context

I'm posting an answer here since I found this question when searching to solve my own problem. In my case I wanted the tab content to occupy all the height. Which sounds similar to your problem, but since the question does not provide any specifics for the problem I will make some assumptions.

### Solution

Since `v-tab__items` will have the height of its content, **create a parent element for the content that has the desired height**, in my case I use the viewport height (note that, since the tabs also have its own height, the content must take that into account). I use this in conjunction with `<v-layout align-center justify-center column fill-height/>`. See the following example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.tab-item-wrapper {
  /* vuetify sets the v-tabs__container height to 48px */
  height: calc(100vh - 48px)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-tabs>
      <v-tab>tab</v-tab>
      <v-tab-item>
        <div class="tab-item-wrapper">
          <v-layout align-center justify-center column fill-height>
            <v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="error" outline>Error</v-btn>
          </v-layout>
        </div>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Note:** I could not find a solution to avoid hardcoding the `tab-height`, by the time being this is [hardcoded on Vuetify styles](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/5ebe7a0b5917a35ec6947263ab4e0a7fbf433f25/src/stylus/components/_tabs.styl#L56) it's not exposed as a [variable](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/464d8192f549b8bedac1a8eed47d2108b9fb0c3c/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl).

**EDIT** Updated snippet starting tag for v-layout was self closing.

Comment: This works great for me.     .tab-item-wrapper {
      height: calc(100vh - 270px);
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

Comment: There is a solution without `calc()`. I've posted an answer. @a--m sorry for the plagiarism in headers formatting, they are cool and easy to read :(

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Vuetify 2.

```
.v-tabs-items.full-height-tab  .v-window-item {
  height: calc(100vh - 270px); /* Adjust 270px to suits your needs */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

<v-tabs-items class="full-height-tab">
    <v-tab-item>...</v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>...</v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Context

I found this question while trying to solve the same problem as [@a--m did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627786/5598194) but their solution does not respect a *single source of truth* principle. If `v-tabs` height changes in the future Vuetify versions, the layout will stop working as expected, and `calc()` will be needed to be rewritten. Logically, our tab items should know nothing about header height.

Moreover, `v-tab-item` should not be inside `v-tabs` but in a separate `v-tabs-items` component.

---

### My solution

Generally it is not a Vuetify issue but a pure CSS problem. It can be solved **just with flexboxes and `overflow` property**, even when **the parent height is computed**.

Please see **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61844861/5598194)** in more specialized thread and the adapted **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gejxpmL/)** example with `v-tabs`.

The only difference in this specific case is a need to use `!important` modifier when you set `overflow: auto` on `v-tabs-items`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for 2 hours. But I found

```html
.tabs__content
    {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for Vuetify 2.3.10:

In the component containing `<v-tabs>`, `<v-tab>` and `<v-tab-item>`, add this to your style:

```
 .v-window__container {
   min-height: 100vh;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can a CSS selector in your single-file component with a larger specificity

```
<style>
  .my-component .v-tab__items
  {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```