# Vuetify equal height v-tab-items

Tags: html, css, tabs, vuetify.js

Please advise how to make vuetify v-tabs content displayed in equal height blocks. I found no options for this component in documentation which can help with height alignment.

By default v-tab-item height depends on its own content height:
[image]  [image]

Layout example:

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <div>
            <v-tabs v-model="active" color="cyan" dark slider-color="yellow">
                <v-tab :key="tab-1">
                    tab 1

                </v-tab>
                <v-tab :key="tab-2">
                    tab 2

                </v-tab>
                <v-tab-item key="tab-1">
                    tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br>
                </v-tab-item>
                <v-tab-item key="tab-2">
                    tab 2 content
                </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs>

        </div>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/olegef/pen/MqKaxQ

Is it possible to align v-tab-items height by tallest v-tab-item using CSS only?

Comment: Just use `height: value;` in your `v-tabs__content` class? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLNRvg)

Comment: If you would like tab items to fill the remaining height you might be interested in this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855170/5598194

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried yet, then setting your desired `height` (not `min-height`[explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341821/height100-vs-min-height100)) value in `v-tabs__content` class.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLNRvg) ...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.v-tabs__content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-tabs v-model="active" color="cyan" dark slider-color="yellow">
        <v-tab :key="tab-1">
          tab 1

        </v-tab>
        <v-tab :key="tab-2">
          tab 2

        </v-tab>
        <v-tab-item key="tab-1">
          tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br> tab 1 content<br>
        </v-tab-item>
        <v-tab-item key="tab-2">
          tab 2 content
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs>

    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: in case tab content is bigger than explicit height setting I face content overflow issue.