# Vuetify equal height v-windows items

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

ibf: there is an old question, which is exactly similar to my problem, it is posted here [Vuetify equal height v-tab-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011553/vuetify-equal-height-v-tab-items), still the offered solution is not i exactly want by many reasons.

I have the widget with it's height, based on it's child `v-window` component. There's a primary `v-window-item`, (probably with static conetnt, but who knows, if it can change in future, so it's height has to be auto or computed at least), and another few with dynamic content, so i want their height to be equal to the first one, when i switch tabs. So the question is there any way to set it up with native vuetify directives or calculate it with css?